# Topological order in Weyl Semimetal

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry, topological-order, topological-phase, weyl-semimetal

Is the topological phase in a Weyl semimetal is intrinsic or symmetry protected? How can we realize that?

If symmetry protected, which symmetry protects the topological phase of non-centrosymmetric Weyl semimetals and magnetic Weyl semimetals?

Comment: It does not require protection from any crystalline symmetries.